# не могу запустить базовый проект в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Попробовал разные методы установки идеи, но в итоге 3-тий день уже сижу на одной и той же ошибке, вообще без понятия как решать(с другими средами никаких ошибок не возникало). jdk установлен 18(разные версии не помогают решить проблему)

[image: скрин ошибки 1]

[image: скрин ошибки 2]

---

Переустановил все на диск c, но тут возникает такой вопрос[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Загуглив сообщение об ошибке: [intellij idea linkageerror jps.cmdline.Launcher UnsatisfiedLinkError sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher](https://www.google.com/search?q=intellij+idea+linkageerror+jps.cmdline.Launcher+UnsatisfiedLinkError+sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher), удалось обнаружить первое же сообщение на сайте [поддержки Jet Brains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4406437278738-Abnormal-build-process-termination-), указывающее на возможную причину проблемы и способ её решения:

> Looks like the JDK compiler fails to initialize due to non-ascii path to the project which contains احمد الزبيدي symbols. The issue similar to https://github.com/eclipse-openj9/openj9/issues/10945
>
> Please try using different JDKs to build the project. If it does not help, please install the JDK (and IDE) into a path that has only ASCII characters in path.

То есть, в пути к директории пользователя (в вашем случае `C:\Users\Николай`) и соответственно `AppData` содержатся символы, отличные от ASCII, которые обрабатываются некорректно.

Попробуйте переустановить JDK и/или IDE IntelliJ IDEA, чтобы они не использовали пути к директориям с кирилличными буквами.

Comment: посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой комментарий ниже